# Automated alert notifications android xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I am new to android development.I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015.

In my project, i want to send **automatic alerts notification** (like in some games or apps a notification shows up after certain time.) on the basis of Time Table stored in a mobile database using SQlite ORM. But i dont know how to implement this feature.Help me sort out this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a Service or IntentService and use NotificationCompat.Builder for the message.
Look on examples in the xamarin web